# javascript code linked in an HTML file does not work in chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, console.log, google-chrome-console

I have a javascript  code in separate file linked with an html file . When I run that html file on chrome,the console does not respond to that linked javascript file.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="myscript.js">
    
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
var x = 0;

while (x<5) {
  console.log('x is currenlty: '+5);
  console.log('adding 1 to x');

  x = x +1;
}
```

I expect the console to respond to print out the console log but on chrome nothing happens.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Replace `type=` with `src=` in HTML.

Comment: If you're going to have type attribute on script then it should be `type="text/javascript"`, at least it should be for JavaScript script content.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "type" instead of "src" on script tag.

```
<script src='myscript.js'></script>
```

If you change this on your code, it will work fine.